# bzip2 on certain files within directory

Tags: linux, unix, compression, tar, bzip2

I have a bzipped folder that contains files within it. The files within it are about 1TB, but I only need about 50GB of them, and if I try to get all the files in the folder, my machine runs out of memory. Here is the command I'm currently using:

```
pbzip2 -dvc -m1000 popularity20151223.tbz |sudo tar x
```

How would I only extract the file called "myfile" from the above tarball? The equivalent of this with `tar` is:

```
tar xpj -C {tarball} {files_to_unarchive}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this similarly with the tar command:

```
pbzip2 -dcv -m1000 /Users/david/Desktop/popularity20151216.tbz
  | tar x popularity20151216/myfile1  popularity20151216/myfile2
```